# Python: Randomly draw several objects in a list

Tags: python, list, random, performance

I am looking for the most efficient way to randomly draw `n`elements in a list given a list of probabilities stating the probability of each element to be picked.

> aList = [3,4,2,1,4,3,5,7,6,4]
>
> MyProba = [0.1,0.1,0.2,0,0.1,0,0.2,0,0.2,0.1]

It means that at each draw, the first element (which is 3) has a probability of 0.1 to be drawn. Of course,

> sum(MyProba) == 1 # always returns True
>   len(aList) == len(MyProba) # always returns True

Up to now I did the following:

```
def random_pick(some_list, proba):
    x = random.uniform(0, 1)
    cumulative_proba = 0.0
    for item, item_proba in zip(some_list, proba):
        cumulative_proba += item_proba
        if x < cumulative_proba:
            break
    return item

nb_draws = 10
list_of_drawn_elements = []
for one_draw in range(nb_draws):
    list_of_drawn_elements.append(random_pick(aList, MyProba))
```

It works but it is terribly slow for long lists and big values of `nb_draws`. **How can I improve the speed of this process?**

Note: In the special case I am facing, nb_draws always equals the length of `aList`.

Comment: Have you tried using Numpy's multinomial class. It does what you want and might be faster if it is implemented in C (I don't know. You have to test it out.) See here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.multinomial.html

Comment: [`numpy.random.choice`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html#numpy.random.choice) is an even closer fit. All the heavy work is done in C, and the algorithm should be more efficient than what you're using.

Comment: You may be interested in reading Bendersky's page on [weighted random choice](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/01/22/weighted-random-generation-in-python/) in Python-- it lists many possible methods and gives performance comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea (as outlined by others' answers as well) is that your method is inefficient because the preprocessing (the calculation of the cumulative distribution) is done every time you draw a sample, although it would be enough to do it once before the sampling and then use the preprocessed data to do the sampling.

The preprocessing *and* sampling could be done efficiently with [Walker's alias method](http://www.keithschwarz.com/darts-dice-coins/). I have implemented it a while ago; take a look at the [source code](https://gist.github.com/ntamas/1109133). (Sorry for the external link, but I think it's too long to post it here). My version requires NumPy; if you don't want to use NumPy, there is a [NumPy-free alternative](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576564-walkers-alias-method-for-random-objects-with-diffe/) as well (on which my version is based).

**Edit**: the explanation of Walker's alias method is to be found in the first link I provided. In a nutshell, imagine that you somehow managed to construct a rectangular "darts board" that is subdivided into parts such that each part corresponds to one of your original items, and the area of each part is proportional to the desired probability of selecting the corresponding element. You can then start throwing darts at random at the darts board (by generating two random numbers that specify the horizontal and vertical coordinate of where the dart ended up) and check which areas the darts hit. The items corresponding to the areas will be the items you have selected. Walker's alias method is simply a linear-time preprocessing that constructs the dart board. Drawing each element can then be done in constant time. In the end, drawing *m* elements out of *n* will have a cost of O(*n*) for preprocessing and O(*m*) for generating the samples, yielding a total complexity of O(*n* + *m*).

Comment: I didn't really try to understand what it does yet but when running the source code I get this error message "line 97: list indices must be integers, not numpy.string_"

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the gist; line 95 should have read `nrand = defaultdict(int)` instead of `rand = defaultdict(int)`. Also added a short explanation of the method to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

here's my lazy method... build a list with expected number of values for the desired distribution, and use `random.choice()` to pick a value from the list.

```
>>> import random
>>>
>>> value_probs = dict(zip([3,4,2,1,4,3,5,7,6,4], [0.1,0.1,0.2,0,0.1,0,0.2,0,0.2,0.1]))
>>> expected_dist = sum([[i] * int(prob * 100) for i, prob in value_probs.iteritems()], [])
>>> random.choice(expected_dist)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try to precalculate the cumulative probability range for each element and make a tree from these intervals. Then you will get a logarithmic complexity for looking up the element corresponding to the generated probability,  instead of linear one that you have now.

Comment: What do you mean "make a tree from these intervals"? How would you implement this? Thank you

Comment: Tree is a search structure. Look for example here:http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/binary-search-tree-library-in-python/ In your case, the data would be your cumulative probability interval: (left, right).

Answer (score 0):

You're calculating `cumulative_proba` each time when you call `random_pick`. I suggest to calculate it outside the method, and use a better data structure to store it, like a binary search tree, which will reduce the time complexity from O(n) to O(lgn).